# Stop from navigating back to an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I have an app with two activities. `MainActivity` (which is the launcher activity) and a `LoginActivity`. As soon as the user launches the app, `MainActivity` is skipped over and `LoginActivity` is displayed. However, if you press the back button, you can still navigate to `MainActivity`. I'm using the following code to stop that from happening, however it is not working.

In `MainActivity` class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you set twice, the last one will be set.

Comment: This works perfectly. I couldn't use the `finish()` method because I had to get back to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just use `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);` ... finish(); will kill the activity as soon as you navigate from it.

Answer (score 0):

just add `finish();` in the last and change flags to `CLEAR_TOP` rather that `CLEAR_TASK`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two options 
First: if you want back to work but MainActivity should not be there on Back then finish() MainActivity.

like

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();//this line will finish MainActivity, then there will no instance of MainActivity in backstack.
```

Second: If you to stop back button to work , you can override OnBackPressed() metjod and remove super from that...then back button will not work (of device).